# how to hide date time from the return view?

Tags: date, time, yii2, hide

I use Yii2 framework and I have a column named "datacreation" (type DATE TIME and value CURRENT TIMESTAMP).
Also, I have this code in my view:

```
                       [
                         'attribute' => 'datacreazione',
                           'value' => function ( $model ) {
                             $stampa= "";
                             if( $model->Utenteupdate ){
                             $tip1= $model->Utenteupdate;
                             $tip1= ($tip1) ? User::findOne($tip1) : null;
                             $tip1n= ($tip1) ? $tip1->id : "";
                             $stampa= ($tip1n);
                           }
                             return $model->datacreazione." utente ".$stampa;
                           },
                         'label' => 'Data creazione']
```

This show me the result: "2020-07-15 11:33:00 utente 734".
Now, I would to hide the date and the timestamp. At the end, the result that I wish is "utente 734", without other information about date and time. I hope to be clear.
Anyone can help me with this code please?
Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build the showed  text in one anonymous associated  to the param value

then in this anonymous  function just return the string for utente 734

```
 return  "utente ".$stampa;
```